# código de java a python pero no se si la sintaxis es correcta

Tags: java, python, lista

```
def comparador(seleccion,matriz,elemento):
  respuesta=0
  posicion=0
  #El for recorre toda la matriz hasta encontrar la seleccion
  for e in len(matriz):
    #Si encuentra la seleccion se procede a verificar sus enemigos
    if matriz[e][posicion]==seleccion:
      #El for verifica a sus enemigos de forma horizontal
       for i in len(matriz[0]):
           #se verifica si el elemento esta dentro de los enemigos de la seleccion
           if matriz[e][i]==elemento:
          #Si se encuentra su respuesta sera 2
             respuesta=2
           elif respuesta !=2:
          #Sino se encuentra la respuesta sera 1  
              respuesta=1
 return respuesta
```

"seleccion" es un int, matriz es una matriz,elemtento es un entero

"Comparador" trae una respuesta puede cambiar a `False` o `True`
1 es si el candidato no esta dentro de la tabla de enemigos
Y 2 si el candidato esta dentro de la tabla de enemigos.

Pero lo primero que el hace es encontrar la fila de la selección asigada a villa
Luego comienza a comparar con los enemigos de esa fila

El problema a solucionar es que comparador recibe una matriz que tiene "1234=paises" y "0=no" tiene conflicto y "1=si" tienen conflicto y si tiene conflicto no pueden ir en una misma villa, ya  tengo otra funcion que me dice quienes son enemigos pero  "Comparador" lo que hace es que recibe la tabla de enemigos, la selección que esta asignada a la villa y el candidato

```
 matriz selecciones                       paises   conflicto con estos paises                 
0 1 2 3 4                                     1          2
1 0 1 0 0                                     2          1 
2 1 0 0 0                                     3          4 
3 0 0 0 1                                     4          3
4 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Como te comenté en la respuesta de otra de tus preguntas, usar los métodos con formato __metodo__ no es correcto, deberías usar `len(matriz)` en este caso. Has copiado y pegado el código que te di sin siquiera mirarlo, no? Porque si no verías que tu loop `for e in e<matriz.__len__():` es incorrecto, si usas IN debes proporcionar un conjunto de valores, no un true/false.

Comment: perdon , ya lo corregi

Comment: Otra cosa, por qué devuelves un 1 o un 2, por qué no true o false?

Comment: ps en el momento lo vimos mejor asi , consideras mejor que retorne un true/false?

Comment: Lo que hace esa función es comprobar si dos paises son enemigos, no? Entonces lo suyo sería que devuelva un true / false. Asignar valores aleatorios (en este caso 1 y 2) a algo que es SI o NO, hace que con el tiempo el programa sea más difícil de entender puesto que tienes que recordar qué era cada valor... VERDADERO o FALSO, en cambio, siempre tienen el mismo significado. Lo mismo pasa con el nombre de las variables y las funciones, si en vez de `comparador()` ves `sonEnemigos()`, si vuelves a tocar ese código tras tres meses sin verlo, sabrás al momento lo que es

Answer (score 2):

Le pasas `seleccion` y `matriz` a la función, y lo primero que hacías era buscar `seleccion` en `matriz`, pero si ya has pasado `seleccion`, para qué quieres pasar la matriz entera para volver a buscarla?
Puedes pasar solo `seleccion` directamente:

```
def comparador(seleccion, elemento):
    if elemento in seleccion:  # Si el elemento está en seleccion
        return True  # Devuelve True, return termina la ejecución así que no devolverá el False si entra
    return False  # Si no entra al if, devolverá False


matriz = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(comparador(matriz, 6))  # False
print(comparador(matriz, 5))  # True
```

Y si lo que necesitas es comprobar que la `seleccion` esté dentro de `matriz` puedes hacerlo así:

```
def comparador(seleccion, matriz, elemento):
    if seleccion not in matriz:  # Si seleccion no está en matriz devuelve false y termina la ejecución
        return False
    # El resto del código no se ejecutará si devuelve el False arriba
    if elemento in seleccion:  # Si el elemento está en seleccion
        return True  # Devuelve True, return termina la ejecución así que no devolverá el False si entra
    return False  # Si no entra al if, devolverá False


matriz_selecciones = [
    [1, 2, 3, 6, 7],
    [2, 1, 5],
    [3, 1],
    [4, 7],
    [5, 2, 7],
    [6, 1, 7],
    [7, 1, 4, 5, 6]
]

sel = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
incorrectSel = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(comparador(sel, matriz_selecciones, 4))  # False
print(comparador(sel, matriz_selecciones, 3))  # True
print(comparador(incorrectSel, matriz_selecciones, 4))  # False porque incorrectSel no está en matriz_selecciones
```

Un saludo.